# SQL Query get all values from left table and uncommon values from right table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all values from the left table (ignoring the common values from the right table with the same id) and all values from the right table that don't exist in left table.

Table 1:

```
----------------------
|   id   |    value  |
----------------------
|   1    |    50     |
----------------------
|   2    |    150    |
----------------------
|   4    |    100    |
----------------------
```

Table 2:

```
----------------------
|   id   |    value  |
----------------------
|   1    |    300    |
----------------------
|   3    |    150    |
----------------------
|   4    |    250    |
----------------------
```

Expected result:

```
----------------------
|   id   |    value  |
----------------------
|   1    |    50     |
----------------------
|   2    |    150    |
----------------------
|   3    |    150    |
----------------------
|   4    |    100    |
----------------------
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please saw your work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `union all` and a `not exists` clause:

```
select id, value
from table1 t1
union all
select id, value
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
(
select * from tab1
except
select * from tab2
UNION ALL
select id, value
from tab2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from tab1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id))d
order by d.id ;
```

**output**

```
id  value
1   50
2   150
3   150
4   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a `Full Join` and a `Coalesce`

```
Select      Coalesce(L.Id, R.Id) Id,
            Coalesce(L.Value, R.Value) Value
From        Table1  L
Full Join   Table2  R On L.Id = R.Id
Order By    Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct *
from
(select id, value
from table1 t1
union all
select id, value
from table2 t2)
```

Comment: your output id value
`1 50
1 300
2 150
3 150
4 100
4 250`